# Is there a way to apply formatting to a value output by Liquid?

Tags: liquid, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am new to Liquid and am using it in the context of the RedmineUp Reporter Plugin. I am running into an issue with formatting being pulled as text and not applied.

For example:
I use `{{issue.description}}` which pulls the description of the issue tracker it is applied to. However, the description is formatted as a table, so my return is

"As of January 5, 2021, the schedule for this release is as follows: `{background:#ddd}. |{width:50%}. Task|{width:20%}. Owner|{width:20%}. Tracker Type|{width:10%}`. Due Date" with the actual contents of the table following that.

Is there a way to pull this out using Liquid, so that it outputs the actual table instead?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by contacting support, who provided an update to the Reporter plugin. With the newest version, it supports the code `{{issue.description | with_formatting}}` which does exactly what I needed.